# Laravel - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: in input field

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project consisting of Sales application, I have this codes:

Controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $suppliers =Supplier::all();
    $categories = Category::all();
    $taxes = Tax::all();
    $units = Unit::all();

    return view('product.create', compact('categories','taxes','units','suppliers'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{

     $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|min:3|unique:products|regex:/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/',
        'serial_number' => 'required',
        'model' => 'required|min:3',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'sales_price' => 'required',
        'unit_id' => 'required',
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'tax_id' => 'required',

    ]);


    $product = new Product();
    $product->name = $request->name;
    $product->serial_number = $request->serial_number;
    $product->model = $request->model;
    $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $product->sales_price = $request->sales_price;
    $product->unit_id = $request->unit_id;
    $product->tax_id = $request->tax_id;


    if ($request->hasFile('image')){
        $imageName =request()->image->getClientOriginalName();
        request()->image->move(public_path('images/product/'), $imageName);
        $product->image = $imageName;
    }

    $product->save();

    foreach($request->supplier_id as $key => $supplier_id){
        $supplier = new ProductSupplier();
        $supplier->product_id = $product->id;
        $supplier->supplier_id = $request->supplier_id[$key];
        $supplier->price = $request->supplier_price[$key];
        $supplier->save();
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Product Created Successfully');
}
```

view

```
    <div class="row mt-2">

        <div class="clearix"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="tile">
                <h3 class="tile-title">Product</h3>
                <div class="tile-body">
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <form method="POST" action="{{route('product.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Product Name</label>
                                <input name="name" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" type="text" placeholder="Product Name">
                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Serial Number</label>
                                <input name="serial_number" class="form-control @error('serial_number') is-invalid @enderror" type="number" placeholder="Enter Tax Name">
                                @error('serial_number')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Model</label>
                                <input name="model" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" type="text" placeholder="Enter Tax Name">
                                @error('model')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Category</label>

                                <select name="category_id" class="form-control">
                                    <option>---Select Category---</option>
                                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                                        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>

                                @error('category_id')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Sale Price</label>
                                <input name="sales_price" class="form-control @error('sales_price') is-invalid @enderror" type="number" placeholder="Enter Tax Name">
                                @error('sales_price')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Unite</label>
                                <select name="unit_id" class="form-control">
                                    <option>---Select Unit---</option>
                                    @foreach($units as $unit)
                                        <option value="{{$unit->id}}">{{$unit->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('unit_id')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Image</label>
                                <input name="image"  class="form-control @error('image') is-invalid @enderror" type="file" >
                                @error('image')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label class="control-label">Tax </label>
                                <select name="tax_id" class="form-control">
                                    <option>---Select Tax---</option>
                                    @foreach($taxes as $tax)
                                        <option value="{{$tax->id}}">{{$tax->name}} %</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('tax_id')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tile">

                            <div id="example-2" class="content">
                                <div class="group row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                                         <select name="supplier_id[]" class="form-control">
                                            <option>Select Supplier</option>
                                            @foreach($suppliers as $supplier)
                                                <option value="{{$supplier->id}}">{{$supplier->name}} </option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                     </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                                         <input name="supplier_price[]" value="{{old('supplier_price')}}" class="form-control @error('supplier_price') is-invalid @enderror" type="number" placeholder="Enter Sales Price">
                                        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->has('additional_body') ? $errors->first('body') : '' }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                        <button type="button" id="btnAdd-2" class="btn btn-primary float-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnRemove float-right"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4 align-self-end">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Update</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I submitted the form, I got this error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View:...

Then when I removed this:

> value="{{old('supplier_price')}}"

from:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
  <input name="supplier_price[]" value="{{old('supplier_price')}}" class="form-control @error('supplier_price') is-invalid @enderror" type="number" placeholder="Enter Sales Price">
     <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->has('additional_body') ? $errors->first('body') : '' }}</span>
 </div>
```

the error vanished.

I wanted to use it for the input field to retain its value after any error in validation. Where did I get it wrong and how do I correct it?

Thank you

Comment: Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlspecialchars function. `htmlspecialchars()` function accepts `string` as its first argument but you are passing an array to it. To solve this issue, for example, you can set an `is_selected` attribute to the array after the form is submitted and retrieve it another way.

Answer (score 0):

`supplier_price` is an array since you define it as `name="supplier_price[]"`

your old() function will output an array while the mustache function `{{}}` expects a string.

If I understand your code properly you should be better off removing the `[]` from  `name="supplier_price[]"`